# Duplicate jar entry org/slf4j/helpers/BasicMarker.class

Tags: android, gradle

I added ****.aar file to app after that I got the following error. What would be the issue and how to fix this

```
(Duplicate jar entry [org/slf4j/helpers/BasicMarker.class]))
```

Answer (score 0):

org/slf4j is duplicated, you can try to fix like ..

```
api (name:'xxx-3.0.0', ext:'aar'){
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}
```

Comment: I did like this   implementation(project( ':LIBS_NAME')) {
        exclude group: "org.sl4j", module: "slf4j-api"
    } still have the issue